# HTML: How to make the clicklistener ignore an invisible button placed on an icon

Tags: javascript, html, css, addeventlistener

I am trying to make a modal window which is triggered by a click on the question mark icon in the below code.

```
<label class="control-label col-md-4 col-lg-3" for="offer_offer" id=Angebotlbl>
   <div class="inline-help form-label" ><i class="fa fa-question-circle-o" id="AngebotHilfe"></i>
      <button id="hilfeBtn" data-modal-target="#modal"></button>
   </div>Angebot</label>
```

I don't really know HTML or .css. After trying and failing to make that icon clickable, I thought about creating a transparent/invisible button and placing it right on top of that icon. The .css looks like this:

```
#hilfeBtn {
        background-color:Transparent;

  -webkit-border-radius: 60;
  -moz-border-radius: 60;
  border-radius: 60px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
  border: solid #1f628d 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
      position:absolute;
    top: 22%;
    left: 5%;
}

##hilfeBtn:hover {
  background: #3cb0fd;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

But probably my plan was stupid. Because now i can't really add an eventlistener to the above icon "Angebothilfe" without the eventlistener ignoring the invisible button on top of it. My eventlistener looks like this:

```
formElements[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        focusFunction(event);
    });

function focusFunction(event) {
      console.log("clickedOn," +event.target.id+","+ Date.now())
```

Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: Why can't you put the event listener directly on the icon? Or on the label that wraps it? I can't see the value of the invisible button, but maybe I missed something?

Comment: I think what you want to do is a tooltip, check this out https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_tooltip.asp

Comment: @see sharper - you're correct: there's probably no need for any "invisible button".  I'd suggest adding an event handler.  AngelSalazar's "tooltip" suggestion is also worth considering.  It depends on what the OP is looking for, exactly...

Comment: @paulsm4 i want a click on the icon ( but not on the label wrapping it ) to fire a modal window and a clicklistener to output the id of that icon and the timestamp.

Comment: So simply put the "onclick()" wherever you need it.  I think you can probably add it directly to your image element, but you can wrap it in a `<span>` and put it there, if you need to.  Experiment with my example below until you get what you want.  Please feel free to post any additional questions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class="inline-help form-label" onclick="myFunction()" >
  <i class="fa fa-question-circle-o" id="AngebotHilfe"></i>
</div>
```

"myFunction()" will do whatever you want.